# Can vegetable oils, extracted from seeds, be shown to cause health problems?

Tags: nutrition

There have been quite a few claims lately on the internet (though all look deceptively similar), that vegetable oils in general are [bad for your health](http://www.thankyourbody.com/vegetable-oils/) and that one should prefer oils which are not extracted from seeds, like [coconut and olive oil](http://wellnessmama.com/2193/why-you-should-never-eat-vegetable-oil-or-margarine/).

Usually, in these claims there is no differentiation between oils - All are equally branded as "unnatural" and therefore bad. In addition, [it is claimed that they are responsible for cardiovascular and other diseases](http://authoritynutrition.com/6-reasons-why-vegetable-oils-are-toxic/).

I am wondering if these claims are correct and whether all vegetable oils can be shown to be collectively problematic to human health, when consumed in regular, day-to-day amounts.

**Are vegetable oils (such as canola, corn, sunflower, etc.) linked to health problems?**

Comment: This question would be greatly improved by focusing on an individual claim that you've heard and asking us if it's true. There is a lot of distracting content in this question that takes focus away from a single claim that we could verify/falsify/examine.

Comment: There are too many claims here. We can't hope to answer "which is healthiest" when there are so many factors. (i.e. What if one is correlated with a terminal cancer, one is causally associated with a milder cancer, one increases the risk of heart-disease, one increases (bad) cholesterol - which is assocated with heart disease, one reduces bio-diversity (through farming practive), one has the highest carbon footprint, one involves GMO, and one is the least organic? Which is "healthiest"?)

Comment: @Oddthinking
Thank you for your contribution. I tried to make my question a bit more specific. The problem I am having is precisely that: There are too many claims in the world of nutrition. When I am asking about "healthiest", I do mean healthy for the consuming individual. organic/non-organic and GMO vs nonGMO has, to my knowledge, not been shown to have anything to do with health and more with ideology.
Reducing bio-diversity is also not a health but an environmental problem, as does having a high carbon footprint.

I hope the question is now improved a bit.

Comment: You've still got to narrow this down. It isn't within the scope of skepticism to balance the various factors affecting individual health and come up with a recommendation about which oil is the healthiest. What we *can* do is evaluate the evidence behind a specific claims, like if you've heard that trans-fats cause X... we can tell you whether or not that is true. Pick one of these oils or fats that you've heard something specific bad about and we can help you evaluate the evidence surrounding that claim. If there are several claims you're interested in, you can make them separate questions.

Comment: @Articuno. I am sorry, but I can't quite see how to narrow it down further. My question pertains specifically to the problem that first, all oils and fats were considered bad, then only some, and then again nearly all of them.

My question is thus if there is a scientific consensus about an oil or fat that is "healthy". Just as in the sense "Are GMOs 'safe'?". Yes, one cannot make a statement that is true for every single GMO ever created, but one can make a general statement, about general safety. Just like that, I was hoping to gain a general consensus about oils and fats.

Comment: Then, the question that you want to ask isn't on-topic for this site. You're asking for a very broad literature review and analysis. This site is about "researching the evidence behind claims you encounter". For a question to be on topic here, you need to present a claim about the world and we will examine the evidence behind it. Any of the things you've heard about fats or oils probably would probably be fine, but pick one at a time.

Comment: Also, when you do narrow this question down, please be more accurate about how you summarize the links you provide. For example, the first link does not say "all fats are bad for you". Rather, it says "some fat in our diets is actually necessary."

Comment: Oddthinking and Articuno, thanks for your help. I hope the question is better now.

Comment: Isn't a coconut a seed?

Comment: [Castor oil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricin) may not be too healthy in certain formulations.

Comment: @Flimzy and olive pits are also used in the production of olive oil, so they've got it wrong on both ends...

Comment: I came and looked at the question again, and it is still too confusing. First up, yes, any food "can be shown to cause health problems"... but have they? "Vegetable oil" is too broad, "seed" is too broad; pick one, or pick a common factor, like a process or molecule. Then pick an actual health problem (cardiovascular disease, lung cancer, etc.) Perhaps, pick an alternative - e.g. more heart disease compared to olive oil, or compared to a low fat diet? Are you talking about otherwise healthy people, or only a subgroup? Are you talking excessive consumption or any at all?

Answer (score 1):

One major concern is the fatty-acid content of these oils.

The major point of contention is about unsaturated fatty acids.

An unsaturated fatty acid is a molecule with "free slots" to bind other molecules (mono-unsaturated as only one slot, poly-unsaturated can have many). So unlike saturated fatty acids which are stable, unsaturated fatty acid are prone to induce many chemical reactions in the body, some of them being necessary to proper function, some of them being bad for health (inflammatory reaction causing degenerative conditions such as cancers).

If you ingest far more unsaturated fatty acids than are necessary for the good reactions, the remaining will still be there and will be available for unwanted reactions.

These fatty acids are necessary in small amount (they are even labeled "essential" as the human body cannot produce them by itself) but too much of it is toxic. As always in toxicology, that's the dose that makes it toxic.

Many vegetable oils tends to have high concentrations of poly-unsaturated fatty acids, but there are exceptions (coconut and palm are mainly saturated, olive is mainly mono-unsaturated).

With these concentrations, it's easy to reach toxic levels.

Some nutrition books in the ancestral/paleo movement touch this subject.
For example:

- Perfect Health Diet (Paul Jaminet and Shou-Ching Shih Jaminet)
- Deep Nutrition (Catherine Shanahan)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Guillaume. Would you happen to have any links/sources to studies which substantiate your claim?

I must admit that this is the first time I have heard that unsaturated fats create "bad" reactions by default when they are overabundant.

Comment: http://www.termedia.pl/Unsaturated-fatty-acids-and-cancer,3,31,0,1.html

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22015690

Comment: http://raypeat.com/articles/articles/unsaturatedfats.shtml

Comment: There is an extensive medical literature on saturated vs non-saturated fats in diet. Why specifically using books on paleo diet as a reference?

Comment: Because these books are what I personnaly got the information from. Feel free to provide other references.

Answer (score 1):

Vegetable oils tend to be higher in omega-6 fatty acids, contributing to the unhealthy,  skewed omega-6 to omega-3 ratio of the typical Western Diet, as described in [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12442909)